# req.body returns 'undefined' - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, axios, routes

When i make a call to my endpoint `/data`, the req.body returns `undefined` in the console. This is my function. Am i missing anything?

```
app.post("/data", function(req, res) {
  const body = req.body;
  const 
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
  };
  axios
    .post(`${BASE_URL}/data`, body, {headers})
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.status === 200) {
        console.log("success", response.data);
        res.send(response.data);
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.error(e);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by adding a body parser:

```
app.use(express.json())
```